# PostgreSQL only returns result when adding additional AND clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT boroughs.name 
FROM boroughs, uniroads 
WHERE uniroads.normalizedName='6 AVENUE' 
AND st_intersects(boroughs.geometry, uniroads.way) 
AND boroughs.name='Brooklyn'

0 results
```

But when I run it, it returns no results. However, I'm able to find the specific row in the table I'd like it to return, and when I add a clause asking for that particular row, it works fine:

```
SELECT boroughs.name 
FROM boroughs, uniroads 
WHERE uniroads.normalizedName='6 AVENUE' 
AND st_intersects(boroughs.geometry, uniroads.way) 
AND boroughs.name='Brooklyn' 
AND uniroads.osm_id='23334071'

1 result
```

I'm using Postgres 9.2.2.0 with PostGIS through Postgres.app.

Comment: Please reserve the use of "bug" or "bugs" - especially on mature products - until after significant testing and verification. It may or may not be, but don't beg it :)

Comment: I really hope I'm doing something wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it could be...

Comment: Reduce your data set and example to the smallest possible that still has the problem, then you either see what your problem is, or your present that smallest problem instance to the community, your current question only prompts guesswork.

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but is it normal in PostgreSQL to select from two tables without joining them in any way whatsoever?

Comment: @Dan: The join condition would appear to be the `st_intersects(boroughs.geometry, uniroads.way)` call.

Comment: Please, add complete `boroughs` and `uniroads` definitions. Sharing the [`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`](http://explain.depesz.com/) output is also much appreciated.

Comment: Also try REINDEX before proceding.

Answer (score 1):

A guess.

`uniroads.osm_id` looks like a Key, therefore it is most likely to be indexed.

`AND uniroads.osm_id='23334071'` clause is causing (another, perhaps?) index to be used, thus this might mean (some?) originally used indexes are corrupted.

Maybe the following might help?

```
REINDEX TABLE boroughs;
REINDEX TABLE uniroads;
```

In any case, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` wanted for both queries, as well as *complete* definitions of tables involved.